# Remove list elements upon keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, event-listener

I'm working on a simple todo list app in JavaScript.

I need to add new items from the input field on a list, and have the ability to remove items from the list.

I wrote all the necessary functions for storing values from input field and adding it to a list. However I am not able to make removing elements work.

HTML, CSS and JS are provided. removeItems() function doesn't work.

```js
const enterBtn = document.getElementById('enter');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const ulList = document.querySelector('ul');
const delBtn = document.querySelector('button');

// Get input from the input field and create a new li itemn in ul list
function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function addDelButtonsToExistingItems() {
  const liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let i = 0; i < liItems.length; i++) {
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
    liItems[i].appendChild(delBtn);
  }
}

// Add delete buttons to already existing items in a document
addDelButtonsToExistingItems();

// to add new items from the input field
function addNewItem() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    const newLiItem = document.createElement('li');
    newLiItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
    newLiItem.appendChild(delBtn);
    ulList.appendChild(newLiItem);
    input.value = '';
  }
}

/**
* To remove items from the list on delete btn pressed
*/
function removeItems(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('remove');
  }
}

/**
* To toggle done class on list items clicked
*/
function toggleDone(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('done');
  }
}

// If enter key is pressed
function addOnEnterKeyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    addNewItem();
  }
}

// To add new items on enter btn clicked
enterBtn.addEventListener('click', addNewItem);

// To add new items on enter key pressed
input.addEventListener('keypress', addOnEnterKeyPressed);

// To toggle the done class
ulList.addEventListener('click', toggleDone);

// To remove the items on del btn click
// ???????
```

```css
.done{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Shipping List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <h3>Get it done today</h3>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>NoteBook</li>
        <li>Pens</li>
        <li>Eraser</li>
        <li>CMPSC 412 book</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated the code a bit to get rid of some of the `const` and simplified the way the `delete` button click event target is found.

Mostly, I've added a class `delete` to the delete buttons, so we can target those specifically without relying on the tag.

I commented the code I changed.

```js
const enterBtn = document.getElementById('enter');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const ulList = document.querySelector('ul');

// Get input from the input field and create a new li itemn in ul list
function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function addDelButtonsToExistingItems() {
  const liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let i = 0; i < liItems.length; i++) {
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    // Let's add a class so we can target it instead of using a tag name.
    delBtn.classList.add('delete');
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
    liItems[i].appendChild(delBtn);
  }
}

// Add delete buttons to already existing items in a document
addDelButtonsToExistingItems();

// to add new items from the input field
function addNewItem() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    const newLiItem = document.createElement('li');
    newLiItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    // Adding a class again.
    delBtn.classList.add('delete');
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('delete'));
    newLiItem.appendChild(delBtn);
    ulList.appendChild(newLiItem);
    input.value = '';
  }
}

/**
 * To remove items from the list on delete btn pressed. We will do this looking at the document.
 */
function removeItem(e) {
  // Since we are watching the document for a click, we can see if the target of the event has the class "delete" and we can remove its parent li.
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
}

/**
 * To toggle done class on list items clicked
 */
function toggleDone(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('done');
  }
}

// If enter key is pressed
function addOnEnterKeyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    addNewItem();
  }
}

// To add new items on enter btn clicked
enterBtn.addEventListener('click', addNewItem);

// To add new items on enter key pressed
input.addEventListener('keypress', addOnEnterKeyPressed);

// To toggle the done class
ulList.addEventListener('click', toggleDone);

// To remove the items on del btn click. We are targeting the document, since the delete elements can update.
document.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<h3>Get it done today</h3>
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li>NoteBook</li>
  <li>Pens</li>
  <li>Eraser</li>
  <li>CMPSC 412 book</li>
</ul>
```